# Symfony form DateType validation

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have this DateType :

```
$builder
    ->add('date', DateType::class, array(
        'widget' => 'single_text',
        'format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy',
        "required"=>true,
        'label' => "jour.date"))
```

When submitting the form with the date being empty, there is no problem whatsoever. It successfully passes

```
if ($form->isValid())
```

in the controller, and an error finally pops out with

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'date' cannot be null
```

The query fails because this can't be null. But I would like it to return the error and not let the form be validated when the date is empty !

As requested, the entity :

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="datetime")
 */
private $date;
```

Thanks ahead.

Comment: Can you show us your entity code?

Comment: Are you sure it's passing isValid with no date? I copied your code to a new instance of FormBuilder and doing `submit([])` followed by `isValid()` returned false.

Comment: @mickadoo you should post this as an answer. Not `submit`ting the form is a nice error to stumble over

Comment: Hi @Joshua, sure I'll post it - always happy to get my rep up :-) but I'd like to check that it is the right answer first since even if you don't submit I think isValid returns false by default.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks. It's passing `isValid`, yes, since the request is in the condition. I'm adding the field in the entity code

Comment: @Veve I think I know you for a long time, même si Dring n'est plus... :)

Comment: @JeremyBelolo Woot! I think I know who you were then, an US Comic character isn't it? ^^

Comment: @Veve something like that... Something like that... Well it's so cool to cross your path once more ! if you want to chat with me come to the chat section ! You might find a room with some name there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [symfony docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#required) on the required option

> This is superficial and independent from validation. At best, if you
>   let Symfony guess your field type, then the value of this option will
>   be guessed from your validation information.

when you call form is valid it relies on the validator service and entity validation mapping to validate your entity.

You need this [constraint](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/NotBlank.html) to set it required

Answer (score 2):

You have to change:

```
$builder
->add('date', DateType::class, array(
    'widget' => 'single_text',
    'format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy',
    "required"=>true,
    'label' => "jour.date"))
```

**TO:**

```
$builder
->add('date', DateTimeType::class, array(
    'widget' => 'single_text',
    'format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy',
    "required"=>true,
    'label' => "jour.date"))
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering but it didn't work. It still passes the validation without any problem. The type is more accurate though so I will keep it anyway